# Is there a way to display columns in a changeable order, depending on the month that the script is run?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Imagine a very simple table that stores the monthly usage for products:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ProductUsage](
    [ProductId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Month1] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Month2] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Month3] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Month4] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Month5] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Month6] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Month7] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Month8] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Month9] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Month10] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Month11] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Month12] [int] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

This stores rolling historic usage - so today (6 March) the column Month3 contains data for March 2019 (the month of March 2020 is extant), Month2 = February 2020, Month1 = January 2020, Month12 = December 2019, Month11 = November 2019 etc.

I need to create a report of product usage backward from now, so the columnns need to be in order
ProductId,
Month2,
Month1,
Month12,
Month11 ...

and so on.  This needs to be refreshable, so in April the order will be:
ProductId,
Month3,
Month2,
Month1,
Month12,
Month11 ...

Can anyone see a nifty way of doing this?  The report will have a local variable of today's date from which the column order can be calculated.

Many thanks

Edward

Comment: I think you might be looking for SQL Views: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_view.asp

Comment: This is going to get ugly. Can the table be rewritten to just have three columns `ProductID | Month | Value`? Then this is a cakewalk with a simple Where predicate and a pivot.

Comment: are you looking for a dynamic query which does a select [month 2],[month 1],[month 12] from table based on the current_date?

Comment: What good is this table going to be next year?

Comment: The "nifty" way of dealing with this is to fix the design. You have a denormalized nightmare here. Follow what @JNevill said and this is painless.

Comment: The table is in SAGE.  The schema cannot be changed.

Answer (score 1):

In pure SQL you cannot change the columns names dynamically, however you could change dynamically the values that relate to each column.

Let's assume that in the original table Month1 stands for Jan, Month2 for Feb., Month3 for Mar. etc.

```
select * from ProductUsage


+-----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+---------+---------+---------+
| ProductId | Month1 | Month2 | Month3 | Month4 | Month5 | Month6 | Month7 | Month8 | Month9 | Month10 | Month11 | Month12 |
+-----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+---------+---------+---------+
|       111 |      1 |      2 |      3 |      4 |      5 |      6 |      7 |      8 |      9 |      10 |      11 |      12 |
|       222 |     21 |     22 |     23 |     24 |     25 |     26 |     27 |     28 |     29 |      30 |      31 |      32 |
+-----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+---------+---------+---------+
```

-

With the suggested approach the columns names will always be Month1, Month2, ... ,Month12 (in that order) but if for example the current month is Mar. then Month1 will hold the values for Feb., Month2 for Jan. Month3 for Dec. etc.

```
declare @month int = 3

select  * 
from   (select  ProductId, val, 'Month' + cast((12 - cast(substring(col,6,2) as tinyint) + @month - 1) % 12 + 1 as varchar(7))  as col
        from    ProductUsage 
                unpivot (val for col in (Month1,Month2,Month3,Month4,Month5,Month6,Month7,Month8,Month9,Month10,Month11,Month12)) u
       ) pu_u 
       pivot(max(val) for col in (Month1,Month2,Month3,Month4,Month5,Month6,Month7,Month8,Month9,Month10,Month11,Month12)) p 



+-----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+---------+---------+---------+
| ProductId | Month1 | Month2 | Month3 | Month4 | Month5 | Month6 | Month7 | Month8 | Month9 | Month10 | Month11 | Month12 |
+-----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+---------+---------+---------+
|       111 |      2 |      1 |     12 |     11 |     10 |      9 |      8 |      7 |      6 |       5 |       4 |       3 |
|       222 |     22 |     21 |     32 |     31 |     30 |     29 |     28 |     27 |     26 |      25 |      24 |      23 |
+-----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+---------+---------+---------+
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/82c38/31/0)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, easy.

```
DECLARE @MesAct numeric
set @MesAct=3

DROP TABLE #ProductUsage
DROP TABLE #meses

CREATE TABLE #ProductUsage(
[ProductId] [int] NOT NULL,[Month1] [int] NOT NULL,[Month2] [int] NOT NULL,[Month3] [int] NOT NULL,
[Month4] [int] NOT NULL,[Month5] [int] NOT NULL,[Month6] [int] NOT NULL,[Month7] [int] NOT NULL,
[Month8] [int] NOT NULL,[Month9] [int] NOT NULL,[Month10] [int] NOT NULL,[Month11] [int] NOT NULL,[Month12] [int] NOT NULL) 

INSERT INTO #ProductUsage VALUES('10000','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12')
INSERT INTO #ProductUsage VALUES('20000','12','23','34','45','56','67','78','89','91','102','113','124')

create table #meses (numMes numeric)
insert into #meses values(1)
insert into #meses values(2)
insert into #meses values(3)
insert into #meses values(4)
insert into #meses values(5)
insert into #meses values(6)
insert into #meses values(7)
insert into #meses values(8)
insert into #meses values(9)
insert into #meses values(10)
insert into #meses values(11)
insert into #meses values(12)

DECLARE  @cols  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT  ',' + QUOTENAME('Month'+CAST(numMes AS VARCHAR)) 
                   FROM #meses 
                   Where numMes<@MesAct  
                   order by numMes desc 
                   FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')
SET @cols = @cols+','+STUFF((SELECT  ',' + QUOTENAME('Month'+CAST(numMes AS VARCHAR)) 
                             FROM #meses 
                             Where numMes>=@MesAct  
                             order by numMes desc 
                             FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')
------------------------------
DECLARE @Script nvarchar(max)

set @Script='select ProductId, '+@cols+' from #ProductUsage'
execute (@Script)
```

Comment: That's actually a `no, not easily`. You're using string aggregation to create a SQL string with `FOR XML PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

Not particularly pretty but this would do it:

```
select  ProductId,
 case datepart(month,getdate()) when 1 then Month12 when 2 then Month1 when 3 then  Month2 when 4 then  Month3 when 5 then  Month4 when 6 then  Month5 when 7 then  Month6 when 8 then  Month7 when 9 then  Month8 when 10 then  Month9 when 11 then  Month10 when 12 then  Month11 end As LastMonth
 ,case datepart(month,Dateadd(month,-1,getdate())) when 1 then Month12 when 2 then Month1 when 3 then  Month2 when 4 then  Month3 when 5 then  Month4 when 6 then  Month5 when 7 then  Month6 when 8 then  Month7 when 9 then  Month8 when 10 then  Month9 when 11 then  Month10 when 12 then  Month11  end As TwoMonthsAgo
 ,case datepart(month,Dateadd(month,-2,getdate())) when 1 then Month12 when 2 then Month1 when 3 then  Month2 when 4 then  Month3 when 5 then  Month4 when 6 then  Month5 when 7 then  Month6 when 8 then  Month7 when 9 then  Month8 when 10 then  Month9 when 11 then  Month10 when 12 then  Month11  end As ThreeMonthsAgo
 ,case datepart(month,Dateadd(month,-3,getdate())) when 1 then Month12 when 2 then Month1 when 3 then  Month2 when 4 then  Month3 when 5 then  Month4 when 6 then  Month5 when 7 then  Month6 when 8 then  Month7 when 9 then  Month8 when 10 then  Month9 when 11 then  Month10 when 12 then  Month11  end As FourMonthsAgo
 ,case datepart(month,Dateadd(month,-4,getdate())) when 1 then Month12 when 2 then Month1 when 3 then  Month2 when 4 then  Month3 when 5 then  Month4 when 6 then  Month5 when 7 then  Month6 when 8 then  Month7 when 9 then  Month8 when 10 then  Month9 when 11 then  Month10 when 12 then  Month11  end As FiveMonthsAgo
 ,case datepart(month,Dateadd(month,-5,getdate())) when 1 then Month12 when 2 then Month1 when 3 then  Month2 when 4 then  Month3 when 5 then  Month4 when 6 then  Month5 when 7 then  Month6 when 8 then  Month7 when 9 then  Month8 when 10 then  Month9 when 11 then  Month10 when 12 then  Month11  end As SixMonthsAgo
 ,case datepart(month,Dateadd(month,-6,getdate())) when 1 then Month12 when 2 then Month1 when 3 then  Month2 when 4 then  Month3 when 5 then  Month4 when 6 then  Month5 when 7 then  Month6 when 8 then  Month7 when 9 then  Month8 when 10 then  Month9 when 11 then  Month10 when 12 then  Month11  end As SevenMonthsAgo
 ,case datepart(month,Dateadd(month,-7,getdate())) when 1 then Month12 when 2 then Month1 when 3 then  Month2 when 4 then  Month3 when 5 then  Month4 when 6 then  Month5 when 7 then  Month6 when 8 then  Month7 when 9 then  Month8 when 10 then  Month9 when 11 then  Month10 when 12 then  Month11  end As EightMonthsAgo
 ,case datepart(month,Dateadd(month,-8,getdate())) when 1 then Month12 when 2 then Month1 when 3 then  Month2 when 4 then  Month3 when 5 then  Month4 when 6 then  Month5 when 7 then  Month6 when 8 then  Month7 when 9 then  Month8 when 10 then  Month9 when 11 then  Month10 when 12 then  Month11  end As NineMonthsAgo
 ,case datepart(month,Dateadd(month,-9,getdate())) when 1 then Month12 when 2 then Month1 when 3 then  Month2 when 4 then  Month3 when 5 then  Month4 when 6 then  Month5 when 7 then  Month6 when 8 then  Month7 when 9 then  Month8 when 10 then  Month9 when 11 then  Month10 when 12 then  Month11  end As TenMonthsAgo
 ,case datepart(month,Dateadd(month,-10,getdate())) when 1 then Month12 when 2 then Month1 when 3 then  Month2 when 4 then  Month3 when 5 then  Month4 when 6 then  Month5 when 7 then  Month6 when 8 then  Month7 when 9 then  Month8 when 10 then  Month9 when 11 then  Month10 when 12 then  Month11 end As ElevenMonthsAgo
 ,case datepart(month,Dateadd(month,-11,getdate())) when 1 then Month12 when 2 then Month1 when 3 then  Month2 when 4 then  Month3 when 5 then  Month4 when 6 then  Month5 when 7 then  Month6 when 8 then  Month7 when 9 then  Month8 when 10 then  Month9 when 11 then  Month10 when 12 then  Month11 end As TwelveMonthsAgo
    from ProductUsage
```

Or, if you really need to have the names of the months as the column headers, you could do this:

```
declare @month varchar(10)
set @month= DateName(month,DateAdd(month, -1,getDate()))
declare @TwoMonthsAgo varchar(10)
set @TwoMonthsAgo= DateName(month,DateAdd(month, -2,getDate()))
declare @Threemonthsago varchar(10)
set @Threemonthsago= DateName(month,DateAdd(month, -3,getDate()))
declare @fourmonthsago varchar(10)
set @fourmonthsago= DateName(month,DateAdd(month, -4,getDate()))
declare @fivemonthsago varchar(10)
set @fivemonthsago= DateName(month,DateAdd(month, -5,getDate()))
declare @sixmonthsago varchar(10)
set @sixmonthsago= DateName(month,DateAdd(month, -6,getDate()))
declare @sevenmonthsago varchar(10)
set @sevenmonthsago= DateName(month,DateAdd(month, -7,getDate()))
declare @eightmonthsago varchar(10)
set @eightmonthsago= DateName(month,DateAdd(month, -8,getDate()))
declare @ninemonthsago varchar(10)
set @ninemonthsago= DateName(month,DateAdd(month, -9,getDate()))
declare @tenmonthsago varchar(10)
set @tenmonthsago= DateName(month,DateAdd(month, -10,getDate()))
declare @elevenmonthsago varchar(10)
set @elevenmonthsago= DateName(month,DateAdd(month, -11,getDate()))
declare @twelvemonthsago varchar(10)
set @twelvemonthsago= DateName(month,DateAdd(month, -12,getDate()))
declare @query varchar(3800)
set @query =
'select ProductId, case datepart(month,getdate()) when 1 then Month12 when 2 then Month1 when 3 then  Month2 when 4 then  Month3 when 5 then  Month4 when 6 then  Month5 when 7 then  Month6 when 8 then  Month7 when 9 then  Month8 when 10 then  Month9 when 11 then  Month10 when 12 then  Month11   end as '+@month+' '+
 ',case datepart(month,Dateadd(month,-1,getdate())) when 1 then Month12 when 2 then Month1 when 3 then  Month2 when 4 then  Month3 when 5 then  Month4 when 6 then  Month5 when 7 then  Month6 when 8 then  Month7 when 9 then  Month8 when 10 then  Month9 when 11 then  Month10 when 12 then  Month11 end As '+@TwoMonthsAgo+' '+
 ',case datepart(month,Dateadd(month,-2,getdate())) when 1 then Month12 when 2 then Month1 when 3 then  Month2 when 4 then  Month3 when 5 then  Month4 when 6 then  Month5 when 7 then  Month6 when 8 then  Month7 when 9 then  Month8 when 10 then  Month9 when 11 then  Month10 when 12 then  Month11 end As '+@ThreeMonthsAgo+' '+
 ',case datepart(month,Dateadd(month,-3,getdate())) when 1 then Month12 when 2 then Month1 when 3 then  Month2 when 4 then  Month3 when 5 then  Month4 when 6 then  Month5 when 7 then  Month6 when 8 then  Month7 when 9 then  Month8 when 10 then  Month9 when 11 then  Month10 when 12 then  Month11 end As '+@FourMonthsAgo+' '+
 ',case datepart(month,Dateadd(month,-4,getdate())) when 1 then Month12 when 2 then Month1 when 3 then  Month2 when 4 then  Month3 when 5 then  Month4 when 6 then  Month5 when 7 then  Month6 when 8 then  Month7 when 9 then  Month8 when 10 then  Month9 when 11 then  Month10 when 12 then  Month11 end As '+@FiveMonthsAgo+' '+
 ',case datepart(month,Dateadd(month,-5,getdate())) when 1 then Month12 when 2 then Month1 when 3 then  Month2 when 4 then  Month3 when 5 then  Month4 when 6 then  Month5 when 7 then  Month6 when 8 then  Month7 when 9 then  Month8 when 10 then  Month9 when 11 then  Month10 when 12 then  Month11 end As '+@SixMonthsAgo+' '+
 ',case datepart(month,Dateadd(month,-6,getdate())) when 1 then Month12 when 2 then Month1 when 3 then  Month2 when 4 then  Month3 when 5 then  Month4 when 6 then  Month5 when 7 then  Month6 when 8 then  Month7 when 9 then  Month8 when 10 then  Month9 when 11 then  Month10 when 12 then  Month11 end As '+@SevenMonthsAgo+' '+
 ',case datepart(month,Dateadd(month,-7,getdate())) when 1 then Month12 when 2 then Month1 when 3 then  Month2 when 4 then  Month3 when 5 then  Month4 when 6 then  Month5 when 7 then  Month6 when 8 then  Month7 when 9 then  Month8 when 10 then  Month9 when 11 then  Month10 when 12 then  Month11 end As '+@EightMonthsAgo+' '+
 ',case datepart(month,Dateadd(month,-8,getdate())) when 1 then Month12 when 2 then Month1 when 3 then  Month2 when 4 then  Month3 when 5 then  Month4 when 6 then  Month5 when 7 then  Month6 when 8 then  Month7 when 9 then  Month8 when 10 then  Month9 when 11 then  Month10 when 12 then  Month11 end As '+@NineMonthsAgo+' '+
 ',case datepart(month,Dateadd(month,-9,getdate())) when 1 then Month12 when 2 then Month1 when 3 then  Month2 when 4 then  Month3 when 5 then  Month4 when 6 then  Month5 when 7 then  Month6 when 8 then  Month7 when 9 then  Month8 when 10 then  Month9 when 11 then  Month10 when 12 then  Month11 end As '+@TenMonthsAgo+' '+
 ',case datepart(month,Dateadd(month,-10,getdate())) when 1 then Month12 when 2 then Month1 when 3 then  Month2 when 4 then  Month3 when 5 then  Month4 when 6 then  Month5 when 7 then  Month6 when 8 then  Month7 when 9 then  Month8 when 10 then  Month9 when 11 then  Month10 when 12 then  Month11 end AS '+@ElevenMonthsAgo+' '+
 ',case datepart(month,Dateadd(month,-11,getdate())) when 1 then Month12 when 2 then Month1 when 3 then  Month2 when 4 then  Month3 when 5 then  Month4 when 6 then  Month5 when 7 then  Month6 when 8 then  Month7 when 9 then  Month8 when 10 then  Month9 when 11 then  Month10 when 12 then  Month11 end AS '+@TwelveMonthsAgo+' '+
' From ProductUsage'
exec (@query)
```

Now, if you'll excuse me, I think I need a shower